# Bind custom buttons based on xev/evtest

Tags: linux, mouse, x11, xorg

I have a mouse with two side buttons.

I've posted the output from `xev` and `evtest` for both buttons:

**xev**

```
EnterNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4600001,
root 0x306, subw 0x0, time 5663259, (11,69), root:(799,121),
mode NotifyNormal, detail NotifyInferior, same_screen YES,
focus YES, state 0

KeymapNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  6   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

EnterNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4600001,
    root 0x306, subw 0x4600002, time 5662311, (30,60), root:(818,112),
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyVirtual, same_screen YES,
    focus YES, state 0

KeymapNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  6   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

**evtest:**

```
Event: time 1420063746.029705, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 90005
Event: time 1420063746.029705, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 276 (BTN_EXTRA), value 1
Event: time 1420063746.029705, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1420063746.165669, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 90005
Event: time 1420063746.165669, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 276 (BTN_EXTRA), value 0

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Event: time 1420063746.165669, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1420063747.373693, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 90004
Event: time 1420063747.373693, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 275 (BTN_SIDE), value 1
Event: time 1420063747.373693, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1420063747.533689, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 90004
Event: time 1420063747.533689, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 275 (BTN_SIDE), value 0
```

How would one approach mapping these buttons to some virtual keys? For example, how would one map these buttons to act as `back` and `forward` ? Or, scrolling up and down?

Comment: Do you have any button press/button release events?

Comment: How would I get those?

Comment: I got as far as using `btnx` for detecting the buttons (which worked) and attempted to asign `BTN_4` and `BTN_5` for scrolling up and down, but to no effect. I'm running `imwheel` in parallel, but I also tested running `btnx` without `imwheel`, to no effect.

Comment: I have a mouse with these event codes working out of the box. They act as back/forward. Anyway this is not a programming question, there is no code.

Comment: True, but unix.stackexchange.com doesn't get as much hits as this one, and no one could answer there, so I tried my luck here :)